# How do I apply both \mathbf and \left to a \langle?

Tags: formatting, bold, delimiters

I want text surrounded by a bold-face `\left\langle ... \right\rangle`.
But when I use `\mathbf` or `\pmb`, I get errors, and when I use `\bm`, it doesn't seem to do anything.
Is there a command that does this?  I don't want to use `\big`, because I want this in a macro that I can use in many different places.

Answer (score 15):

`bm`  works for me:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{bm}

\DeclareBoldMathCommand\boldlangle{\left\langle}
\DeclareBoldMathCommand\boldrangle{\right\rangle}


\begin{document}

$ \left<a\right> $

$ \bm{\left<a\right>} $

$ \boldlangle a\boldrangle$

\boldmath

$ \left<a\right> $

\end{document}
```

**Update** after clarification from comments...

OK take a step back.

`\mathbf` switches the font used for *math letters* usually to the same font uses for `\textbf` ie upright bold. So *by design* it does not affect the font used for symbols.

`boldsymbol` essentially makes a box, switches to `\boldmath` and then goes back in to math (with some technicalities to get the right size and spacing) so *by design* makes as much go bold as possible. However in the classic cm font distribution there is no bold extension font so LaTeX does not have a line

```
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{bold}{OMX}{cmex} {bx}{n}
```

because there is no such font, so the bold math setup uses the normal weight extension font as you saw.

It may well be that a newer math font collection has more bold fonts (I don't have it now but I'm sure MathTime did for example) but the set of fonts available to you depends on whether you have commercial fonts and whether you are using classic Tex or xetex or luatex that can more easily use system fonts.

`\pmb` is poor man's bold so it has almost no dependencies but is typographically rather dubious if over used, it literally just sets its argument three times with small horizontal and vertical offset. So as seen below it will make its entire argument bold with almost no restrictions on what that argument is.

If you want to make just the delimiters bold using `\pmb` you need to make an invisible rule of the right size (that's what `\vphantom` does) and then you can separately `\pmb` a delimiter pairing before and after the main expression.

`\bm` First tries to add a bold symbol from the math bold setup to the normal weight setup, and if it can not do that either because the bold math setup is using the same font, or you have already used 16 fonts in the current math setup, it uses a version of `\boldsymbol` (if the bold font is different) or a version of `\pmb` otherwise. However immediately after `\left` or `\right` its choices are a lot more limited as TeX is in a rather delicate state at that point.

So best would be to look around the available math fonts to find one with a bold extension font, otherwise one of the `\pmb` variants below will probably do what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{amsmath,bm} 
\DeclareBoldMathCommand\boldlangle{\left\langle} 
\DeclareBoldMathCommand\boldrangle{\right\rangle} 

\def\sigh#1{%
\pmb{\left\langle\vphantom{#1}\right.}%
#1%
\pmb{\left.\vphantom{#1}\right\rangle}}
\begin{document}

 \[ \left\langle \boldlangle a\boldrangle\right\rangle \] 

\[\left\langle \boldlangle \sum_{i=1}^n \boldrangle \right\rangle\] 

{\boldmath
\[\left\langle \boldlangle \sum_{i=1}^n \boldrangle \right\rangle\] 
}

\[\pmb{\left\langle \sum_{i=1}^n\right\rangle}\]

\[ \left\langle\sigh{\sum_{i=1}^n}\right\rangle\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  I hadn't known about DeclareBoldMathCommand.

Comment: However, `$ \pmb{\langle} a \pmb{\rangle} $` seems to be a much more distinctive form of bold than what this achieves.  I know this sounds like whining, but for our paper we need the bold to look very different from the non-bold.
Any ideas?  I tried looking at the DeclareBoldMathOperator code in bm.sty, but couldn't figure out how that was fundamentally different from what I was doing (or attempting to do) manually.

Comment: `\bm` is giving you the bold font, cm fonts are not particularly heavy. Mathtime (for which bm was originally written) has two bold and a "heavy" ultrabold weight, or you may find one of the other math font setups has a suitably more bold font. ``\pmb` on the other hand just prints the character three times offset slightly so it smudges out. It would be tiresome (but not that hard) to write a macro that measured some text to get the right size for the delimiter and then used pmb, but you need a syntax like `\foo{content}` producing `<content>` so that you have the entire content to measure.

Comment: Thanks again for the answer.  I see that my original question was imprecise, in that I didn't realize mathbf, bm, pmb were not all equivalent.
However, your solution doesn't quite address my problem, which more precisely is that the boldface appears to go away when the delimiter is enlarged (which is the whole reason for the \left, \right).  You can see that in this modified version of your file, in which the bold and regular delimiters look the same.
(modified version in a separate comment because of character limit) Sorry, I don't know how to do linebreaks here.

Comment: `\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{bm}

\DeclareBoldMathCommand\boldlangle{\left\langle}
\DeclareBoldMathCommand\boldrangle{\right\rangle}

\begin{document}
\[ \left\langle \boldlangle a\boldrangle\right\rangle \]
\[\left\langle \boldlangle \sum_{i=1}^n \boldrangle \right\rangle\]
\end{document}`

Comment: The best way to add clarifying text/examples is to update you question (so it is easier to add formatted code and people see it later) rather than in comments. I updated my answer.

Comment: @MatemáticosChibchas I assume that's what I meant, fixed thanks:-)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem that I wanted really really bold (probably very ugly) langle/rangle pairs which scale properly. So my solution (more dirty than quick) was to do some kind of pmb myself, putting things to the extreme:

```
\newcommand{\ReallyFatInnerProduct}[1]  {%
\langle\mspace{-6.8mu}%
\langle\mspace{-6.8mu}%
\langle\mspace{-6.8mu}%
\langle\mspace{-6.8mu}%
\langle{#1}%
\rangle%
\mspace{-6.8mu}\rangle%
\mspace{-6.8mu}\rangle%
\mspace{-6.8mu}\rangle%
\mspace{-6.8mu}\rangle}
```

Feel free to add some more of them ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\boldsymbol`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}
  $ \boldsymbol{\left\langle a\right\rangle} $
  $ \boldsymbol{\left\langle a\right\rangle} $
  $ \boldsymbol{\langle a\rangle} $
  $ \boldsymbol{\left\langle a\right\rangle} $
\end{document}
```