# Bold \rrbracket \llbracket

Tags: math-mode, symbols, bold, boldmath

I am trying to define the following four commands and use them as shown below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}

\newcommand{\lqm}[1]{\left\llbracket#1\right\rrbracket_{\mbox{\tiny \rm L}}}
\newcommand{\rqm}[1]{\left\llbracket#1\right\rrbracket_{\mbox{\tiny \rm R}}}
\newcommand{\ldqm}[1]{\left\boldsymbold{\llbracket}#1\right\boldsymbol{\rrbracket}_{\mbox{\tiny \rm L}}}
\newcommand{\rdqm}[1]{\left\boldsymbold{\llbracket}#1\right\boldsymbol{\rrbracket}_{\mbox{\tiny \rm R}}}

\begin{document}

    \begin{equation}
        \lqm{a}, \rqm{a}, \ldqm{a}, \rdqm{a}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

I am having a hard time finding how to make the `\llbracket` or `\rrbracket` bold, since `\boldsymbol` won't work and I am trying to not use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.

Comment: Please edit your two snippets of code so they form *one* single and complete `.tex` file. It makes it easier for everyone else to try to help you.

Comment: Essentially you're looking for [How do I apply both `\mathbf` and `\left` to a `\langle`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47979/5764)

Answer (score 2):

From the link suggested by Werner, this did it for me:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{stmaryrd}

\newcommand{\ldqm}[1]{ \pmb{\left\llbracket\vphantom{#1}\right.}  #1   \pmb{\left.\vphantom{#1}\right\rrbracket} }

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \ldqm{\sum_{\frac{2}{3}}^{7}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```