# Norm with bold bars without bold text inside

Tags: boldmath, bar, boldsymbol

I defined my norm as:

```
\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\lVert#1\right\rVert}
```

And my bold norm as:

```
\newcommand{\bnorm}[1]{\boldsymbol{\norm{#1}}}
```

But I want to write something like `\bnorm{x^{(i)}}` where I don't want the exponent to be bold. I tried

```
\boldsymbol{\left\lVert} x \boldsymbol{\right\rVert}
```

but due to the closing brackets `left` doesn't find `right` and it gives an error. Any ideas?

Comment: Possibly related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47979/218142

Comment: @LaTeXereXeTaL You are right. They are related. Since I don't mind switching from newcommand to declareoperator it solved my problem. What's the best course of action now. Answering my own question, marking it as duplicate or deleting it?

Comment: As far as I am aware, answering one's own question is perfectly fine. If you feel your question is a duplicate, marking it as such would be fine too.

Comment: @LaTeXereXeTaL Do you think it will be considered a good practice to answet it in case anyone stumble upon it and then mark it as duplicate to give them mods the chance to decide?

Comment: Yes, that would be my opinion.

Comment: @LaTeXereXeTaL I did so. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @RomainPicot If you click the link in the first comment it points to the same answer. If you read the followup discussion I answer my question based on the linked one and them mark my question as duplicate because I wasn't sure if it counts. Thank you though.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is:

```
\usepackage{bm}

\DeclareBoldMathCommand\blvert{\left\lVert}
\DeclareBoldMathCommand\brvert{\right\rVert}
\newcommand{\boldnorm}[1]{\blvert#1\brvert}
```

And then use it like:

```
\boldnorm{\boldsymbol{x}^{(i)}}
```